# How to use a generic type?

Tags: ada, ada95

I'm working through the example here: https://www.adahome.com/rm95/rm9x-12-08.html

I've written my `generic_stack.ads`:

```
generic
    type Item_Type is private;
    size : Positive;

package Generic_Stack is
    procedure push( item : in Item_Type );

    function  pop return Item_Type;

    function  is_Empty return Boolean;

    STACK_EMPTY : exception;
    STACK_FULL  : exception;

end Generic_Stack;
```

And my `generic_stack.adb`:

```
package body Generic_Stack
is
    type Stack_Table is array (Positive range <>) of Item_Type;
    nodes : Stack_Table( 1..size );
    index : Natural := 0;

    procedure push( item : in Item_Type )
    is
    begin
        if ( index < size )
        then
            index := index + 1;
            nodes(index) := item;
        else
            raise STACK_FULL;
        end if;
    end push;

    function pop()
    return
        Item_Type
    is
        item : Item_Type;
    begin
        if ( index > 0 )
        then
            item := nodes( index );
            index := index - 1;
        else
            raise STACK_EMPTY;
        end if;
        return item;
    end pop;

    -- function is_Empty()   removed for the sake of brevity
end Generic_Stack;
```

I don't really understand how to actually use the `Generic_Stack`.
With the simple `generic_stack_test.adb`  code:

```
with Generic_Stack;
package Stack_Int_Type is new Generic_Stack( Item_Type => Integer, Size => 32 );

procedure Generic_Stack_Test
is
    stack : Stack_Int_Type;
begin
    stack.push( 3 );
end Generic_Stack_Test;
```

Gnat gives me errors on compilation:

```
# gnat make -gnat95 generic_stack_test.adb -o generic_stack_test
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 -c -gnat95 generic_stack_test.adb
generic_stack_test.adb:9:08: keyword "body" expected here [see file name]
generic_stack_test.adb:20:24: missing "end Stack_Int_Type;"
x86_64-linux-gnu-gnatmake-8: "generic_stack_test.adb" compilation error
```

Do I have to `declare` the `Stack_Int_Type` or suchlike?  I don't understand how to use a declare inside a procedure.  If I pass a `Stack_Int_Type` to another procedure, does it have to declare the type too?

Is it possible to simply declare `Stack_Int_Type` *once* in an `.ads`, and use it as a regular type?  My book and web-pages kind of suggest it has to be declared every time, which sounds onerous.

Comment: Ah, code is Ada12(?) syntax, and I'm stuck on Ada95.

Comment: Simply remove the preconditions and the post-conditions to make it compatible with Ada 95.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test code is actually two library items:

```ada
with Generic_Stack;
package Stack_Int_Type is new Generic_Stack( Item_Type => Integer, Size => 32 );
```

declares a library package `Stack_Int_Type`, and

```ada
procedure Generic_Stack_Test
is
    stack : Stack_Int_Type;
begin
    stack.push( 3 );
end Generic_Stack_Test;
```

declares a library procedure which, as it stands, knows nothing about `Stack_Int_Type`.
We can fix that by adding the necessary `with`, but (compiling with `-gnatl`)

```
 1. with Stack_Int_Type;
 2. procedure Generic_Stack_Test
 3. is
 4.    stack : Stack_Int_Type;
               |
    >>> subtype mark required in this context
    >>> found "Stack_Int_Type" declared at stack_int_type.ads:2

 5. begin
 6.    stack.push( 3 );
       1    2
    >>> invalid prefix in selected component "stack"
    >>> prefixed call is only allowed for objects of a tagged type

 7. end Generic_Stack_Test;
```

What’s happening here is that `Generic_Stack` doesn’t declare a type, so you can’t declare an instance of it at line 4; it’s a sort of singleton. (Amongst other things, that means it’s confusingly named: I’d’ve called it `Integer_Stack`. Never call a package `_Type`; `_Types`, maybe.)
Fixing that,

```ada
with Generic_Stack;
package Integer_Stack is new Generic_Stack( Item_Type => Integer, Size => 32 );
```

and

```ada
with Integer_Stack;
procedure Generic_Stack_Test
is
begin
   Integer_Stack.push( 3 );
end Generic_Stack_Test;
```

You could have made `Integer_Stack` local:

```ada
with Generic_Stack;
procedure Generic_Stack_Test
is
   package Integer_Stack
   is new Generic_Stack( Item_Type => Integer, Size => 32 );
begin
   Integer_Stack.push( 3 );
end Generic_Stack_Test;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to get the test-code working.

Answer (score 2):

Your Generic_Stack package never defines a stack data type. 
The procedure Push and Pop are operations on a stack. You must have a type upon which to operate. There are two general categories of stacks; bounded stacks and unbounded stacks. You must decide which kind of stack you wish to create.
A discussion of both kinds of stacks implemented in Ada can be found at https://sworthodoxy.blogspot.com/2019/02/stack-abstract-data-type-using-ada.html

In the examples referenced in the URL above you will see how to create stack types that can be used multiple times. The example from Adahome is an old and problematic example. You have identified the biggest problem.

Comment: `Generic_Stack` is an Abstract State Machine (ASM), in which the package is the object and only provides operations. While unusual for a stack abstraction, an ASM is a good design approach in many cases.

Comment: The linked `bounded_stack` code gives errors compiling for Ada95 (after pre & post conditions are removed) ~ for the line `S.Push (I);` -> `>>> no selector "Push" for private type "Stack" defined at bounded_stack.ads:9`.  Works fine with default Ada version Gnat 8.4 builds using.

Answer (score 1):

As explained elsewhere, no type is defined by your package specification. Otherwise, you would have `type ... is` somewhere after the `package` keyword. It's that simple.

But as explained elsewhere too, it's not dramatic. Your package instantiation will define exactly **one** stack, and not a type to be used in multiple places. In some cases, it's exactly what you need. So, your could call your instantiated package `My_Stack`, which actually articulates around an object (`My_Stack.nodes`, accessible only through `Push` & `Pop`).

You need to do the instantiation of `Generic_Stack` from within a unit (procedure, package, ...). Outside of it, it is the "outer space" only with `with` and `use` clauses needed to connect with other units.

```
with Generic_Stack;

procedure Generic_Stack_Test
is
    package My_Stack is new Generic_Stack( Item_Type => Integer, Size => 32 );
begin
    My_Stack.push( 3 );
end Generic_Stack_Test;
```